# Why doesn't cups detect my canon selphy USB printer

Tags: printing, cups

I recently upgraded my system to a fresh install of Linux Mint 16.  I was hoping that would support my Canon Selphy CP770, since that is claimed to be supported by the new version of Gutenprint. However, the system isn't detecting it, and the printer config has no option to add a USB printer.

```
pts/0:0:~>lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 006: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c018 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 03f0:6411 Hewlett-Packard PhotoSmart C8100 series
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04a9:31aa Canon, Inc. SELPHY CP770
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 058f:9254 Alcor Micro Corp. Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub


pts/0:1:~>sudo /usr/lib/cups/backend/usb
DEBUG: Loading USB quirks from "/usr/share/cups/usb".
DEBUG: Loaded 67 quirks.
DEBUG: list_devices
DEBUG: libusb_get_device_list=9
DEBUG2: Printer found with device ID: MFG:HP;MDL:Photosmart C8100 series;CMD:MLC,PCL,PML,DW-PCL,DESKJET,DYN;1284.4DL:4d,4e,1;CLS:PRINTER;DES:L2526A;SN:MY79JD701404YH;S:038008C4840010210078cb0000041bd800346b8006447b8006444b8001b48b8006445b8001d;Z:0102,05000009316a81013241013241013241013241013241,0620,070000000000000000000000000000,0b000000000000000098129841000098b798f4000098ba98f9000098b898e7000098b798f9000098b798d8,0c0; Device URI: usb://HP/Photosmart%20C8100%20series?serial=MY79JD701404YH&interface=1
direct usb://HP/Photosmart%20C8100%20series?serial=MY79JD701404YH&interface=1 "HP Photosmart C8100 series" "HP Photosmart C8100 series" "MFG:HP;MDL:Photosmart C8100 series;CMD:MLC,PCL,PML,DW-PCL,DESKJET,DYN;1284.4DL:4d,4e,1;CLS:PRINTER;DES:L2526A;SN:MY79JD701404YH;S:038008C4840010210078cb0000041bd800346b8006447b8006444b8001b48b8006445b8001d;Z:0102,05000009316a81013241013241013241013241013241,0620,070000000000000000000000000000,0b000000000000000098129841000098b798f4000098ba98f9000098b898e7000098b798f9000098b798d8,0c0;" ""
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this [article](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1200) Linux Mint doesn't provide any softare to configure local printers out of the box. You should install `system-config-printer-gnome` package and run `system-config-printer` which will allow you to add your USB printer to CUPS.